# ip country php or apache

Tags: php, apache

i want to validate if the user enter his correct information (city, region, country) from my registration form.

i want to use maxmind because its free and 99.5% accurate (which is good enough for me)

now i read there's a php version and a apache version

http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip

http://www.maxmind.com/app/php

which one is better to use? thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Apache version does the lookup and puts the values into two environment variables. This means it'll do it for every request, plus you will need to take the values from the variables and use them somehow.

The PHP version does the lookup when you call it, i.e. you only need do it during the registration process, plus if you are writing the site with PHP you are half way there already.

I'd recommend using the PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this myself, but if portability is a concern then I'd look into the PHP version as you wouldn't have to modify the actual Apache installation.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the PHP version, unless you need to a geo-ip lookup every request. 
Small design query... Why validate it if you think you already know where he is? If you are going to treat the IP lookup as accurate, then maybe you should prefill that section of the form with the city, and let the user raise a flag if its wrong?

On a side note, The lookup is about 99% accurate on a country basis, but gets markedly worse the more granular you go.